# How to include Intel MKL in Abaqus subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine, intel-mkl, abaqus

I am trying to include the in-build subroutines of Intel Math Kernel Library in ABAQUS UMAT.
I included 'mkl.fi' but it is showing the error as shown below (It is ABAQUS generated job file):

---

```
Abaqus JOB Job-1
Abaqus 6.13-1

Begin Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines

3/8/2017 6:14:23 PM

Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on 
Intel(R) 64, Version 17.0.1.143 Build 20161005

Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.


C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(29): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE CGEJSV( JOBA, JOBU, JOBV, JOBR, JOBT, JOBP,            &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(30): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                  M, N, A, LDA, SVA, U, LDU, V, LDV,              &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(34): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      COMPLEX           A( LDA, * ),  U( LDU, * ), V( LDV, * ),         &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(43): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE ZGEJSV( JOBA, JOBU, JOBV, JOBR, JOBT, JOBP,            &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(44): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   M, N, A, LDA, SVA, U, LDU, V, LDV,             &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(48): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      DOUBLE COMPLEX     A( LDA, * ),  U( LDU, * ), V( LDV, * ),        &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(57): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE DGESVDX( JOBU, JOBVT, RANGE, M, N, A, LDA, VL, VU,     &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(58): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   IL, IU, NS, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK,         &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(64): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * ), S( * ), U( LDU, * ),              &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(70): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE SGESVDX( JOBU, JOBVT, RANGE, M, N, A, LDA, VL, VU,     &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(71): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   IL, IU, NS, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK,         &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(77): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      REAL               A( LDA, * ), S( * ), U( LDU, * ),              &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(83): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE CGESVDX( JOBU, JOBVT, RANGE, M, N, A, LDA, VL, VU,     &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(84): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   IL, IU, NS, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK,         &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(91): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      COMPLEX            A( LDA, * ), U( LDU, * ), VT( LDVT, * ),       &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(97): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE ZGESVDX( JOBU, JOBVT, RANGE, M, N, A, LDA, VL, VU,     &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(98): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   IL, IU, NS, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK,         &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(105): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      COMPLEX*16         A( LDA, * ), U( LDU, * ), VT( LDVT, * ),       &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(111): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE CGESVJ( JOBA, JOBU, JOBV, M, N, A, LDA, SVA, MV, V,    &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(121): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE ZGESVJ( JOBA, JOBU, JOBV, M, N, A, LDA, SVA, MV, V,    &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(131): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE DGGSVD3( JOBU, JOBV, JOBQ, M, N, P, K, L, A, LDA, B,   &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(132): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   LDB, ALPHA, BETA, U, LDU, V, LDV, Q, LDQ, WORK,&
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(135): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      INTEGER            INFO, K, L, LDA, LDB, LDQ, LDU, LDV, M, N, P,  &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(138): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * ), ALPHA( * ), B( LDB, * ),          &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(139): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
     &                   BETA( * ), Q( LDQ, * ), U( LDU, * ),           &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(145): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
      SUBROUTINE SGGSVD3( JOBU, JOBV, JOBQ, M, N, P, K, L, A, LDA, B,   &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(146): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: * <IDENTIFIER>
     &                   LDB, ALPHA, BETA, U, LDU, V, LDV, Q, LDQ, WORK,&
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(149): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      INTEGER            INFO, K, L, LDA, LDB, LDQ, LDU, LDV, M, N, P,  &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(152): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
      REAL               A( LDA, * ), ALPHA( * ), B( LDB, * ),          &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\mkl\include\MKL_lapack.FI(153): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER> %FILL
     &                   BETA( * ), Q( LDQ, * ), U( LDU, * ),           &
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
AFEM.for(170): catastrophic error: Too many errors, exiting
compilation aborted for AFEM.for (code 1)
Abaqus Error: Problem during compilation - D:\Google Drive\Friday_May_27_2016\Mtech Thesis Job\All new work\TA\AFEM.for
Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors
```

---

In case when MKL library is not included, job file shows the following errors:

```
----------
Abaqus JOB Job-1

Abaqus 6.13-1

Abaqus License Manager checked out the following licenses:


Begin Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
3/8/2017 6:18:48 PM

Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 17.0.1.143 Build 20161005

Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.


End Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines

Begin Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines


Creating library standardU.lib and object standardU.exp

AFEM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgemm referenced in function umat.R

standardU.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Abaqus Error: Problem during linking - Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines.

This error may be due to a mismatch in the Abaqus user subroutine arguments.
```

These arguments sometimes change from release to release, so user subroutines
  used with a previous release of Abaqus may need to be adjusted.

Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors

---

The source code, when compiled outside ABAQUS, works fine with no errors. 
If I am not able to include this lapack library in ABAQUS UMAT subroutine, I may have to append lapack source code in my code itself. That may invite other problems.

So is there any way to compile these lapack subroutines in ABAQUS successfully.
Note that ABAQUS User subroutine (UMAT) is written in '.for' format.
I have included the UMAT (ABAQUS subroutine) for reference. It has 'mul_big_mat' (that stands for multiplying big matrices) subroutine that uses lapack 'dgemm' subroutine.

---

```
    C================================================================

          SUBROUTINE UMAT(STRESS,STATEV,DDSDDE,SSE,SPD,SCD,
         1RPL,DDSDDT,DRPLDE,DRPLDT,STRAN,DSTRAN,
         2TIME,DTIME,TEMP,DTEMP,PREDEF,DPRED,MATERL,NDI,NSHR,NTENS,
         3NSTATV,PROPS,NPROPS,COORDS,DROT,PNEWDT,CELENT,
         4DFGRD0,DFGRD1,NOEL,NPT,KSLAY,KSPT,KSTEP,KINC)
    C
          INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
    C
          CHARACTER*80 MATERL
          DIMENSION STRESS(NTENS),STATEV(NSTATV),
         1DDSDDE(NTENS,NTENS),DDSDDT(NTENS),DRPLDE(NTENS),
         2STRAN(NTENS),DSTRAN(NTENS),TIME(2),PREDEF(1),DPRED(1),
         3PROPS(NPROPS),COORDS(3),DROT(3,3),
         4DFGRD0(3,3),DFGRD1(3,3)
    C
          DIMENSION EELAS(6),EPLAS(6),FLOW(6)
          PARAMETER (ONE=1.0D0,TWO=2.0D0,THREE=3.0D0,SIX=6.0D0)
          DATA NEWTON,TOLER/10,1.D-6/
    C
    C ============================================================================
    C     UMAT FOR 1D BAR
    C 

    ============================================================================
        C     Note :- This UMAT can only be used by 1D elements
        C
        C     Number of material properties, nprops = 1
        C     props(1)         Young's modulus in x direction
        C ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        C
              ! --- local variables
              DOUBLE PRECISION E
              DOUBLE PRECISION C(ntens, ntens)
              integer z
        !***********************************************************************

        ! *** Get Elastic properties
              E = props(1)
              write(*,*)''
              write(*,*) z
              write(*,*)''
        ! *** Elastic stiffness Cijkl *** !
              C(1,1) = E
              !call hello_world3
              CALL mul_big_mat

        ! *** calculate the stress *** !
              stress(1) = C(1,1)*(stran(1) + dstran(1))

        !     Updating Jacobian matrix
              ddsdde(1,1) = C(1,1)
              return
              END

              subroutine hello_world3
              implicit none
              character*32 text
        c
              write(*,*)'Hello World'
        c
              END

              subroutine mul_big_mat    
        c
        c
              integer m, n, k, i, j
              parameter (m=100,  k= 200, n=100)
              double precision a(m,k), b(k,n), c(m,n), alpha, beta
              alpha=1.0
              beta=0.0
        c      matrix a declaration       
              do i=1,m
                  do j=1,k
                      a(i,j)=i+j
                  enddo
              enddo
              write(*,*) a(100,200)
        c      matrix b declaration       
              do i=1,k
                  do j=1,n
                      b(i,j)=i-j
                  enddo
              enddo
              write(*,*) b(200,100)
        c      matrix c declaration       
              do i=1,m
                  do j=1,n
                      c(i,j)=0.0
                  enddo
              enddo
              call dgemm('n','n',m,n,k,alpha,a,m,b,k,beta,c,m)
! THIS IS THE SUBROUTINE I WANT TO USE FROM INTEL MKL LIBRARY
! I COULD USE MATMUL (AND THAT WORKS FINE), BUT ITS JUST AN EXAMPLE
! I HAVE TO USE 'DGETRI' AND MANY MORE
              write(*,*) c(1,1)
              do i=1,m
                  do j=1,n
                      write(*,*) ' '
                      write(*,*) c(i,j)
                  enddo
              enddo
              END
```

Comment: the copy of "MKL_lapack.FI" i found by google appears to be intended to be fixed-or-free compatible.  Check your copy and make sure the ampersand at the end of the line is in column 73 (or more), and the one on the following line is in exactly column 6.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are compiling a free-form (.f90) file as a fixed-form (old FORTRAN 77 style) file. You cannot use & at the and of the line in fixed form .f or .for file.

Your source file is a `.for` file (`AFEM.for`) sou your code should be in the fixed form. You can try whether ABAQUS supports the `-free` compiler flag to force free-form. If it doesn't you must use the fixed form everywhere.

Be careful not to mix parts of fixed-form and free-form in one file. The file `MKL_lapack.FI` seems not to be compatible with your original source. You unfortunately do not show how you are including this.

---

HOWEVER, you should not really need to include the include file at all! You should just link with the right library. Use the Intel MKL Link Line Advisor https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor to derive the correct linker flags.